# How to set initial grouping for a Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, grouping, server-side, kendo-ui-mvc

So I've got the following piece of code working server side using Kendo Grid. However, I am confused on the next step.

How do I set the grid to initially group by Income_Party? Also is it possible to add in a total amount per grouping?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.IncomeView)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(model => model.INC_INCOME_DESCRIPTION);
      columns.Bound(item => item.INC_INCOME_AMOUNT);
      columns.Bound(item => item.INC_INCOME_PARTY);
      columns.Template(@<text>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MyLink" + item.VIEW_TYPE, new { id = item.GID, ReturnAction = "IncomeAndExpenses" }, null)  
                 </text>)
                  .ClientTemplate("<a href='/brunch/statistics/brunchid=#= BrunchCode#'>#=BrunchCode#</a>")
                  .Title("");
  })
```

)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the initial groups and aggregates like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.IncomeView)
  .Name("grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(model => model.INC_INCOME_DESCRIPTION);
      columns.Bound(item => item.INC_INCOME_AMOUNT).GroupFooterTemplate(@<text>
            Total: @item.Sum
        </text>);
      columns.Bound(item => item.INC_INCOME_PARTY);
      columns.Template(@<text>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "MyLink" + item.VIEW_TYPE, new { id = item.GID, ReturnAction = "IncomeAndExpenses" }, null)  
                 </text>)
                  .ClientTemplate("<a href='/brunch/statistics/brunchid=#= BrunchCode#'>#=BrunchCode#</a>")
                  .Title("");
  })
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Server()
        .Aggregates(aggregates =>
        {
            aggregates.Add(p => p.INC_INCOME_AMOUNT).Sum();
        })
        .Group(groups => groups.Add(p => p.INC_INCOME_PARTY))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a million - will give it a shot quickly! Appreciate you help.

Comment: Work perfectly. Thanks a mil!